ConnectApi.NamedCredentials.getNamedCredential method not working for non admin users
I'm using ConnectApi.NamedCredentials.getNamedCredential() method to get the details of the named credentials in apex.
For an admin user, the code is working fine from the Execute Anonymous window of the developer console but when the same code is excuted in context of a non-admin user, it is giving the below exception.
FATAL_ERROR System.NoAccessException: Insufficient Privileges: This feature is not currently enabled for this user.
Running user's license is 'Salesforce', few other posts suggested to add API Enabled permission which has been added. Named credential is not being accessed from a managed package.

This is strange, we found out that the permission 'Allows users to modify Named Credentials and External Credentials' is required to fetch named credentials using ConnectApi. In my opinion, it should not be made required to have modify permission to only fetch the named credentials and not perform any update operation.

does that specific non-admin user have access to User External Credentials object?
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.fsc_admin_enable_user_access_to_user_external_credentials_object.htm&type=5
Named credentials reference external credentials, which specify authentication protocols and authorization information. In turn, external credentials use user external credentials to store encrypted authentication tokens. Any user performing an authenticated callout needs profile- or permission set-based access to user external credentials.
From Setup, in the Quick Find box, enter Profiles, and then select Profiles.
Click the profile for whom you want to enable user external credentials.
Scroll to Standard Object Permissions and find User External Credentials.
Select the box for Read permission.
Save your changes.
This is something we always provide to users using named credentials.
